# Can't install Ubuntu because I don't have enough free space

Tags: 12.04, installation, windows-8, hp

This is my first post and my first day using any Linux-based operating system. Two days ago I dropped my HP Windows 8 laptop. I got the error:

```
Boot device not found. Please install an operating system on your hard disk. Hard disk (3f0).
```

I couldn't access any files or the OS, so I went on my sister's computer, researched and learned about Ubuntu. I saved Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS to a disk and loaded it, but when I tried to install it, I had it connected to the power adaptor and the wifi, however there was not enough free space to install it. How do I view and delete files from the *Try Ubuntu without installing* mode?

TLDR - Is there a way to delete previous files if I can't dual boot, using the "uninstalled version" of Ubuntu 12.04.3?

Comment: "I dropped my laptop" together with "Boot device not found" sounds to me like your harddisk might be broken. If that is the case even Linux won't be able to help.

Comment: @Nodebody Or the connection to the hard disk may have been dislodged (which, as hardware problems go, is very easy to fix).

Comment: @EliahKagan, sure that's definitely worth checking. My point was that from the description of the problem, to me, it doesn't sound like anything a new operating system or software in general could fix.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot access your system and you want just access and manage the data of your hard disk, I think you can allways use the DVD "try before install", just delete the files on your hard disk, and then you can install it normally.

Take a look at this for instructions: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install

I hope it help

Comment: I am in the try before install but don't see any of my files!!!

Answer (score 0):

What you really need to do is mount your existing filesystem. Now how do you do that?

Simple, really, the Unity launchbar which would be on your left hand side, would have an icon of a folder, that's where you can access everything from. I've attached a picture here, which can serve as a reference. Now under Devices, (look at the image), you'll have your existing data disks, for example in my screenshot, you can see Data Disk 1 &2. These are my Windows disks, when i click on them they get mounted and i can access all my data, while running my Ubuntu system. Delete whatever you'd like to and unmount the filesystem. Upon unmounting, Ubuntu would ask you if you'd like to delete all the items that you sent to trash, which when you agree to basically, clears all those items out for good, and it is necessary that you agree to clearing those items out. That way, you can create enough space for your Ubuntu installation.

[image: Devices and Filesystems]